# Kendo combo box not functional after adding cdkcopytocliboard module

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I have a form with a few controls which include kendo combo boxes, some input fields of type text and buttons. This is a functional form where all the controls are working good.

When I added the cdkcopytoclipboard module to the appmodule, the combo boxes are not displaying the options. They are not loading on the page load. Only the first item in the combo box is visible.
If I remove this cdkcopytoclipboard module , they start functioning well.

Any idea what could be causing this ?

Thanks in Advance